# Jquery on click event not firing every touchup on my android browser

Tags: jquery, onclick, android-browser

#### html

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" title="item detail" class="menu-list" name="1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="item detail" class="menu-list" name="2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="item detail" class="menu-list" name="3">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".menu-list").on("click", function(){
    //not fired every click!
    return false;
});
```

It fired. But not fired every touchUp! on my android mobile browser.
(It fired every click on Chrome of pc)
Why this phenomenon is occurred?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Technically, mobile browsers use  touchstart/touchend with jQuery Mobile (http://jquerymobile.com/), but newer versions of jQuery may be more lenient.

Comment: Currently, I'm using 1.8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not the problem of onClick.

Inside callback function, the append code not work properly.